# Netbeans and osgi bundle development

Tags: netbeans, osgi, apache-felix

I'm about to star an OSGI project using netbeans 6.8 and felix 2.0.4; can anybody provide me with tips and/or links to get started quickly ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at the support for OSGi that is being baked into NetBeans 6.9.  [NetBeans/OSGi integration is mentioned in the New and Noteworthy document](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteWorthy).  Since this work is targeted for release in NB 6.9, you may have trouble finding info about integrating NB 6.8 and OSGi.

I would recommend that you [download NetBeans 6.9 milestone 1](http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/6.9/m1/) and contribute to project by providing feedback.